# How to keep inside a branch changes you don't want to commit

Tags: git

Say I have a project with a master branch and I created Feature branch.

```
$ git checkout -b Feature
```

I created FileA, FileX
I changed FileB, FileY

I’m finished with my new feature, I want to push only FileA and FileB, but leave FileX and FileY intact on the remote, so I commit only the first two.

```
$ git commit FileA FileB
$ git push
```

Now I want to go back on master or another branch for a completely different feature, but the changes I did to FileX and FileY are still haunting my folder. If I don’t care about them, I could do:

```
$ git checkout -- FileY  // which will discard FileY changes. (FileY was changed)
$ rm FileX // (FileX was created)
```

But what if I want to keep thoses changes for later in case I need to go back working on Feature?
What's the best way to keep changes you don't want to commit inside a branch?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `git stash`. It will save your work and remove it from the work tree. You can regain the work by using `git stash pop`.

An example:

```
$ git status -s
 M a
?? b
$ git add b # You have to add b before stashing, since git will ignore this file otherwise
$ git stash
$ git status -s
# Nothing ...
```

You can find the documentation [here](http://git-scm.com/docs/git-stash).

Answer (score 1):

Use [git stash](http://git-scm.com/docs/git-stash) after commit:

> Use git stash when you want to record the current state of the working
>   directory and the index, but want to go back to a clean working
>   directory. The command saves your local modifications away and reverts
>   the working directory to match the HEAD commit